# EditText.getText().toString() in a fragment returns empty

Tags: java, android-edittext

I am trying to get an EditText.getText().toString() in a fragment working, I have already read all other questions on this issue but cannot find the solution: I have the EditText.getText().toString() in the onClick method for a confirm button after inflating the view, I have checked that the id of the button is correct, but I am not finding the error.
In the logcat I can see that the method saveWord which is called after the line in question is called correctly - just the String that is supposed to be filled with the editText is always empty. If I put a hardcoded string on the variable, it works as expected.

Would be very glad if anyone could help! Might be just a silly mistake I am overlooking?

This is my code:

```
public class BingoAddNewFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String LOG_TAG = BingoDataManager.class.getSimpleName();

View v;

public static final String DEFAULT_EDIT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "editFragmentTag";


private Button mConfirmButton;
EditText mAddWords;

String newWord;

String bWord1 = ""; 
String bWord2 = ""; 
String bWord3 = ""; 
String bWord4= ""; 
String bWord5= ""; 
String bWord6= ""; 
String bWord7= ""; 
String bWord8= ""; 
String bWord9= ""; 
String bWord10= ""; 
String bWord11= ""; 
String bWord12= ""; 
String bWord13= ""; 
String bWord14= ""; 
String bWord15= ""; 
String bWord16= ""; 

String[] bWord = {bWord1, bWord2, bWord3, bWord4, bWord5, bWord6, bWord7, bWord8, bWord9,
        bWord10, bWord11, bWord12, bWord13, bWord14, bWord15, bWord16};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_bingo_fragment, container, false);

    //some other stuff

    mConfirmButton = v.findViewById(R.id.button_confirm);

    mAddWords = v.findViewById(R.id.editText_addWords);

    mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //The next line is not working (everything else seems fine) ->
            newWord = mAddWords.getText().toString();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Begriff: " + newWord + " wird übergeben");
            saveWord (newWord);

        }
    });

    mSaveButton = v.findViewById(R.id.button_save_bingo);

    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveBingo();
        }
    });


public String[] saveWord (String newWord) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Wort: " + newWord + " entgegengenommen.");

    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,  "i steht bei: " +i);
        if (bWord[i].equals("")) {
            bWord[i] = newWord;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Word als " + (i+1) + ". Begriff gespeichert.");
            break;
        }
    }
    return bWord;
}
```

And this is an extract of my layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorLightBlue">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_addWords"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/input_word"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"
        android:textColorHint="@drawable/selector"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_confirm"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.31"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_title" />
```

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on a `String`?

Comment: Because it is an EditText that needs to be casted (not sure if this is the right word) on a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - though I am still not sure why it did not work.
I changed the buttons into ImageButtons and suddenly it works perfectly fine.